# How to persistently delete default grease pencil brushes?

Tags: python, grease-pencil

I'm working on 2D animation with a set of brushes for each character and i scripted an add-on to import this brush set from another .blend file.

I'm now struggling with the removal the default brushes, `bpy.data.brushes.remove(bpy.data.brushes['Airbrush'])` works fine at first sight, but i notice now that the default brushes are loading again every time i switch to draw mode.

```
import bpy

bpy.data.brushes.remove(bpy.data.brushes['Airbrush'])
try :
    if bpy.data.brushes['Airbrush'] :
        print('not deleted')
except KeyError :
    print('no more airbrush') #it prints this line
    
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'PAINT_GPENCIL')

try : 
    if bpy.data.brushes['Airbrush'] :
        print('Airbrush came back !!') #Airbrush always comes back !
except KeyError :
    print('no more airbrush')
```

Is there a way to permanently delete these brushes or prevent them from reloading ?
Thanks !